# change dynamic meta tags in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Iam trying to change the meta tags dynamically, iam using [ngMeta tags](https://github.com/vinaygopinath/ngMeta) but it is not working i mean there is no update in meta tags

here is my html code

```
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{facebookAppId}}">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ngMeta.title}}">
  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ngMeta.title}}">
  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ngMeta.description}}">
  <meta property="og:url" content="{{ngMeta.url}}">
  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ngMeta.url}}">
  <meta property="og:type" content="website">
```

here is controller code

```
angular.module('core').controller('HomeController',['$scope','ngMeta'],function($scope,ngMeta){

 ngMeta.setTitle('Demo page');
    ngMeta.setTag('description', 'This is the description of the demo page');
    ngMeta.setTag('image', 'http://mobilemarketingwatch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Is-Google-Searching-for-the-Next-Big-Thing1.jpg');

});
```

here is my routes

```
angular.module('core').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'ngMetaProvider',function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, ngMetaProvider) {

 $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/home.html'         
      })
      .state('aboutus', {
        url: '/aboutus',
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/about.html',
        data: {
          pageTitle: 'About '
        }
      });

}]).run(['ngMeta', function (ngMeta) {
  ngMeta.init();
}]);
```

In home page also it not showing any title. please solve my problem

here is the image of my browser console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with dynamic meta tags or ngMeta. You haven't associated `HomeController` with the `home` state. Refer [ui-router docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers)

```
    .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
          })
```